# Spring Security исключить url из защищенной директории

Tags: java, spring

есть метод

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin*/**")
            .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/admin/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(604800).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

мне нужно `/admin/login` исключить из защищенной директории, чтоб по этому url можно было обратиться любому пользователю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно прописать игнорируемые адреса в специальном методе вашей реализации класса `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)

```
override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/admin/login")
}
```